# Android put left border line on a image in xml Drawable

Tags: android, imageview, border, line, drawable

I need to put a orange line in the left side of a imageview. I put in "the hard way" and it works:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="5dp"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:background="#FF7F24" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/image1"
             android:layout_width="50dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp" 
          />

    </LinearLayout>
```

There is a way to do this effect using a drawable xml file in the image directly without using the linearlayouts?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a [shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and set it as the background of your LinearLayout instead of "#FF7F24".
But since you only want a solid color, I think the way you implemented it is just fine

Comment: Thanks, if I don't find any other way to do it I keep this solution

Answer (score 2):

Use this below code as a drawable to imageview

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FF7F24" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp">
    <bitmap android:shape="rectangle" 
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</item>
```

Comment: I can't put the image from a src because I load it from database. When I try to use a style in background the orange line is inside the image but this is not the effect that I want.